# different result for [[ ]] and [] string comparator "<"

Tags: bash, sh

I was doing some tests, and I couldn't understand why there two results are different. The first one seems correct, since in a crescent ordenation, the character 'f' comes first than 'F'

```
$ [[ "Foo" < "foo" ]]
$ echo $?
1
```

So why this one is incorrect?

```
$ [ "Foo" \< "foo" ]
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: [The POSIX `test` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) doesn't specify `<` **at all**. There's no behavior it's guaranteed to have, so if your goal is portability, you absolutely shouldn't use it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: But if you're using bash, you can reasonably rely on the features it provides.

Comment: @KeithThompson, sure, but if you're exclusively targeting bash, you should be using `[[ ]]` (and not including the `sh` tag on your questions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `[[` and `[` are built into `bash`.  `[` is equivalent to the `test` command, also a builtin.  (Well, almost equivalent; `[` requires a matching `]`, `test` doesn't.)

According to the bash manual:

> When used with `test` or `[`, the `<` and `>` operators sort
>   lexicographically using ASCII ordering.

(Bourne shell builtins are documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html)).

But the expression in `[[` ... `]]` follows the rules of [*Bash conditional expressions*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html):

> When used with `[[`, the `<` and `>` operators sort
>   lexicographically using the current locale.  The `test` command uses
>   ASCII ordering.

(There's another `test` / `[` command provided as part of the GNU coreutils package, typically `/usr/bin/test`. This command doesn't provide `<` and `>` operators, which are not specified by POSIX. The external command should be irrelevant if you're using bash, unless you explicitly give the full path `/usr/bin/test`.)

Your question is tagged both "bash" and "sh". If you're using bash, you should probably use the bash-specific `[[` feature rather than `[`. If you want greater portability (e.g., if your script might be used with a shell other than bash), you can't rely on the `[[` builtin, and you can't assume that `[` or `test` supports `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 2):

The BSD `test` implementation of `<`<sup>[1]</sup>, like the bash-builtin one, is not character-collation-order aware; it refers only to "the binary value" of the characters in question.

The bash `[[ ]]` implementation of `<` **is** characterset-aware: It honors the current language/locale's selected collation order.

If you set `LC_COLLATE=C` (specifying ASCII sort order), then `[[ ]]` will do the same:

```
$ (export LC_COLLATE=C; [[ "Foo" < "foo" ]]; echo $?)
0
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> - `>` is not a [POSIX-standardized `test` operator](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), so all answers *must* be in the context of a specific implementation.

Comment: There are two distinct GNU implementations of `test` / `[`. One is an external command, part of the coreutils package, but the relevant one here is the bash builtin command. The coreutils `test` command does not provide `<` and `>` operators.

Comment: @KeithThompson, hmm, you're right -- it's a BSD one I was looking at the documentation for that does provide `<` and `>`.